# How do I troubleshoot a UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer error?

Tags: c++, string

I'm solving a leetcode problem where I have to find the longest palindrome within a string and return it. I got the main algorithm written down pretty quickly, and it was passing some simple test cases locally, but when I tried to run it remotely from within leetcode, I got the following error:

```
Line 1061: Char 9: runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x7fff1f221c60 overflowed to 0x7fff1f221c5f (basic_string.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/bits/basic_string.h:1070:9
```

All of the research that I did in the next few hours led me to believe that I must be accessing or editing some code that was out of bounds of the string. Unfortunately, no matter how thoroughly I check to make sure it's impossible to use an out-of-bounds index, I'm getting the same error.

This is my code as it currently exists:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Solution {
public:
    std::string longestPalindrome(std::string s) {
        std::string pal = "";
        short pal_offset = 0;

        for (size_t pivot = 0; pivot < (s.size() - (pal.size() / 2)); ++pivot) {

            // Check for odd palindrome at pivot
            pal_offset = 0;

            // Make sure pivot + next offset doesn't overflow s to the right
            // Make sure pivot - next offset doesn't overflow s to the left
            if ((pivot + (pal_offset + 1) < s.size()) && (pivot - (pal_offset + 1) >= 0)) {

                // Check the next possible offset to see if substring is still a palindrome
                while (s[pivot + (pal_offset + 1)] == s[pivot - (pal_offset + 1)]) {
                    // Confirm that current offset works
                    ++pal_offset;
                    // Double check that the new offset can't overflow to either side
                    if (pivot < pal_offset || (pivot + pal_offset) >= s.size())
                        break;
                }
            }

            // If there is a confirmed offset greater than 0 and that offset is greater than all previous
            // offsets
            if (pal_offset && pal.size() < (pal_offset * 2) + 1) {

                // Gonna be silly and double check here to make sure the bounds of the substring don't
                // overflow s from the left or the right
                if (pivot - pal_offset >= 0 && (pivot + ((pal_offset * 2) + 1) < s.size())) {
                    // Stick that new, big palindrome into pal
                    pal = s.substr((pivot - pal_offset), ((pal_offset * 2) + 1));
                }
            }

            // Check for even palindrome at pivot and pivot + 1
            // Why am I starting at -1? Well, let me tell ya. Pull up a chair. In order to be consistent
            // with the odd checker, I decied to follow the following algorithm algorithm:
            //   1) Check the offset that is one greater than the last known good offset
            //   2) If it works, make *that* the last known good offset, and go back to 1
            // Because even palindromes start at offset 0 (the pivot is part of the palindrome), we have
            // to have the default last known good offset set to -1, so that the 'next' one in the first
            // run is 0.
            pal_offset = -1;

            // Make sure pivot - the next offset doesn't overflow s on the left 
            // Make sure pivot + 1 + the next offset doesn't overflow s on the right 
            if ((pivot - (pal_offset + 1) >= 0 ) && ((pivot + 1) + (pal_offset + 1) < s.size())) {

                // Check the next possible offset to see if substring is still a palindrome
                while (s[pivot - (pal_offset + 1)] == s[(pivot + 1) + (pal_offset + 1)]) {
                    // If it is a palindrome, increment pal_offset to show the new confirmed offset
                    ++pal_offset;
                    // Just be really silly and double check that we're not going to be overflowing with
                    // our next check.
                    if (pivot < pal_offset || (pivot + pal_offset) >= s.size() - 1)
                        break;
                }
            }

            // If the greatest confirmed offset is greater than or equal to 0 (remember that an even
            // palindrome like "aa" will have a greatest offset of 0) and if the current palindrome is
            // larger than any others
            if (pal_offset >= 0 && pal.size() < (pal_offset + 1) * 2) {

                // Make sure that we are not going to access out of bounds memory here
                if ((pivot - pal_offset >= 0) && ((pivot - pal_offset) + (pal_offset + 1) * 2) < s.size()) {
                    pal = s.substr((pivot - pal_offset), ((pal_offset + 1) * 2));
                }
            }
        }
        return pal;
    }
};

int main() {
    Solution sol;

    std::cout << sol.longestPalindrome("babad") << std::endl;
    std::cout << sol.longestPalindrome("babbad") << std::endl;
}
```

I hope the rubber ducky comments aren't too distracting. What can I do to get more information about where this error is coming from? What does it even mean? Is there a straightforward way to fix it?

Comment: This is a good time to remind you of the `at` function which performs bounds checks. When you have a mystery bug with the smell of an illegal access, swap `[]` for `at` and see where the exception gets thrown.

Comment: I didn't realize at() did bounds checking! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things.

`(pivot - (pal_offset + 1) >= 0)` will always be true, because `pivot` is an unsigned type, so the entire expression will be unsigned.

In the `while` loop inside that `if`, when `pivot == pal_offset` (which can happen with an odd length string) you will try to access `s[-1]`, which is illegal (and a possible source of the runtime error you're getting).